# Fijar tamaño de un button

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

Estoy buscando una forma de fijar el tamaño de un button, sin importar el tamaño del texto que tenga adentro, ya que van a ser números que no van a pasar de 3 cifras

Les dejo un ejemplo para que vean de lo que hablo (también en [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t72vf024/1/)):

```css
.table-mesas {
  float: left;
  width: 95.8%;
}

.table-mesas tr td {
  padding: 15px;
}

.butt-mesas {
  -webkit-border-radius: 4;
  -moz-border-radius: 4;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #666666;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  background: #88dd77;
  border: solid #000000 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.butt-mesas:hover {
  background: #9ae288;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #666666;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-mesas">
  <tr>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">1</button></td>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">2</button></td>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">3</button></td>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">4</button></td>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">5</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">100</button></td>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">2</button></td>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">3</button></td>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">4</button></td>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">5</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">1</button></td>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">2</button></td>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">3</button></td>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">4</button></td>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">5</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">1</button></td>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">2</button></td>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">3</button></td>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">4</button></td>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">5</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">1</button></td>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">2</button></td>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">3</button></td>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">4</button></td>
    <td><button class="butt-mesas">5</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes probar estableciendo una anchura y altura fija, y un "line-height" igual a la altura que le hayas puesto, para que el texto aparezca en el centro verticalmente. Además, un text-align: center, para centrar el texto horizontalmente.

```css
button {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button>1</button>
<button>10</button>
<button>100</button>
```

Espero haberte ayudado. Un saludo.

Comment: Las unidades px, puedes reemplazarlas por em o rem. O calculas el ancho y alto y divides por el número de filas y columnas menos el espacio entre ellos haciendo con CSS: width|height: calc((100% / 5) - 30px);

Comment: Se lo que comentas, pero solo he dejado un ejemplo funcional para que le haga el apaño.